# Swift 4 - How to convert Json to swift Object automatically like Gson in java

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json, swift4

I am new in Swift 4 and trying to figure out How to convert Json to swift Object automatically like Gson in java. Is there is any plugin i can use which can convert my json to object and vice versa. I have tried to use SwiftyJson Library but couldnt understand what is syntax for directly converting the json to object mapper.
 In Gson conversion is as follow :

```
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(obj);
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);
```

Can you please suggest some really simple example for beginner like me . below is my swift person class :

```
class Person  {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

below is method call to fetch response from server :

```
let response = Helper.makeHttpCall(url: "http://localhost:8080/HttpServices/GetBasicJson", method: "PUT", param: interestingNumbers)
```

In response variable I am getting json:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "doe"
}
```

Comment: Swift 4 introduces `Codable` protocol & `JSONEncoder` / `JSONDecoder` for this purpose. [Here](http://swiftjson.guide) is a really comprehensive guide on this topic.

Comment: Yes, seems like Codable is a solution. However, it still requires typing unlike Gson!

Answer (score 29):

There's no need for external libraries in Swift anymore. As of Swift 4, there are 2 protocols that can achieve what you are looking for: [Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) and [Encodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) which are grouped into the [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) typealias, as well as [JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder).

You just need to create an entity that conforms to `Codable` (`Decodable` should be enough in this example).

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let firstName, lastName: String
}

// Assuming makeHttpCall has a callback:
Helper.makeHttpCall(url: "http://localhost:8080/HttpServices/GetBasicJson", method: "PUT", param: interestingNumbers, callback: { response in
    // response is a String ? Data ?
    // Assuming it's Data
    let person = try! decoder.decode(Person.self, for: response)

    // Uncomment if it's a String and comment the line before
    // let jsonData = response.data(encoding: .utf8)!
    // let person = try! decoder.decode(Person.self, for: jsonData)
    print(person)
})
```

More info:

- [Apple's sample code: Using JSON with Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types)
- [SE-0167: Swift Encoders](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0167-swift-encoders.md)
- [In-depth guide to JSON parsing in Swift 4](http://swiftjson.guide)
- [JSON with Encoder and Encodable](https://swiftunboxed.com/stdlib/json-encoder-encodable/)
- [JSON to Swift with Decoder and Decodable](https://swiftunboxed.com/stdlib/json-decoder-decodable/)

Comment: Right, but when is a JSONArray what do you use?! You have wrap it in a "JSONObject"?

Comment: No. You can use `let persons = try! decoder.decode([Person.self], for: response)`

Comment: What is decoder in this instance? As Decoder is a protocol it can be instantiated. Showing your declaration for decoder would be a big help.

Comment: @paul_f very late reply but since nobody answered and it might save a couple of minutes for others the decoder instance is actually `let decoder = JSONDecoder()`. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder)

Answer (score 2):

As @nathan Suggested

> "There's no need for external libraries in Swift anymore."

But If you still want to go with the third party library like `ObjectMapper`

```
class Person : Mappable {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    required init?(map:Map) {

    }

   func mapping(map:Map){
      //assuming the first_name and last_name is what you have got in JSON
      // e.g in android you do like @SerializedName("first_name") to map
     firstName <- map["first_name"]
     lastName <- map["last_name"]
   }

}




let person = Mapper<Person>().map(JSONObject:response.result.value)
```

and extending the answer by @nathan to demonstrate `@SerializedName` annotation equivalent in iOS using `Codable`

```
struct Person : Codable {

        let firstName : String?
        let lastName : String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case firstName = "first_name"
                case lastName = "last_name"
        }

}
```